# how generate report between the two dates using datepicker,ajax,php,mysql.?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, datepicker

I have been given a task to generate a report between two given dates using datepicker,ajax,php and mysql. below is my html:

## Date wise Report

```
        From date: <input type="text" id="fromdate" value="">   To date: <input type="text" id="todate" value="" onChange="showuser(document.getElementById('fromdate').value,document.getElementById('todate').value)">  
        <br>
        <div id="txtHint"><b>User informathions will be listed here.</b></div>
```

Scripts:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#fromdate" ).datepicker();
    $( "#todate" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(fromdate,todate)
{
  if (fromdate =="" && todate=="")
    {
     document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
     return;
    } 

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
     {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
     }
  else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
     xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
     if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","bet_date.php?fromdate="+fromdate+"&todate="+todate,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Here is the php file which is supposed to generate the report:
bet_date.php

```
include("database.php"); 
$fromdate=$_GET["fromdate"];
$todate=$_GET["todate"];
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE date between '$fromdate' and '$todate'";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);

 echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>date</th>
<th>start</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>email</th>
<th>phone</th>
<th>comments</th>
<th>approved</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['start'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['comments'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['approved'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

The problem is when I select both the date then nothing happens.
kindly help me in this situation.
simple examples would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Does the php return something if both date are present? DB has record for both cases?

Comment: Yes database has records in it.

Comment: Tried the query with a db management tool like phpMyAdmin?

Comment: yes, i tried it in phpMyadmin using: SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE date between '2014-12-09' and '2014-12-13' and it returned the result properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your html to this:you have `showUser()` not `showuser()` so change in input `onchage="showUser()".`

write `onchange` event to both the inputs.so on both fields they will trigger. and in your sql use date(date) if you are sending only date from front-end and date column in database is of type datetime..

```
"SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE date(date) between '$fromdate' and '$todate'";


  From date: <input type="text" id="fromdate" value="" onChange="showUser()">   To date: <input type="text" id="todate" value="" onChange="showUser()"> 

function showUser()
{

var fromdate = $( "#fromdate" ).val();
var todate= $( "#todate" ).val();

// rest of your code:




}
```

hope you are getting post/get parameters properly in php.

Comment: I am using GET,is it correct syntax: xmlhttp.open("GET","bet_date.php?fromdate="+fromdate+"&todate="+todate,true);

Comment: date is of type date only

Comment: just use echo $sql; and see what it gives.

Comment: if that big table is not visible then how come echo $sql would be visible,first thing i wish ask you,are those my above files correct?

Comment: yes they looks correct.use print_r($sql); and see in console see what it gives.

Comment: @DineshSuthar you are not using the html which i have suggested you are calling showuser() but your function is showUser().

Comment: because you do not have showuser.see the updated answer.

Comment: Ok ok,silly mistake..i got the correct output now..Thank you suchit very very thank you.

Comment: @DineshSuthar then mark it as an answer if your problem is solved.

Answer (score 2):

```
I have Created Whole Tutorial for Date Wise Report, so once try it
```

Table structure

```html
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookings` (
  `id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `start` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `comments` longtext NOT NULL,
  `approved` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `bookings` (`id`, `date`, `start`, `name`, `email`, `phone`, `comments`, `approved`) VALUES
(1, '2014-12-17', 'yes', 'Mahendra', 'mahendra@XXXX', '89XXXXXXXX', 'nothing', 'yes'),
(2, '2014-12-18', 'no', 'Rahul', 'rahul@XXXXXX', '987XXXXXXX', 'very nice article', 'yes');
```

my_test.php

```js
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#generate_report").click(function(){
   var from_date=jQuery("#fromdate").val();
   var to_date=jQuery("#todate").val();
   var data =
   {  
    from_date  : from_date,
  to_date   : to_date
   }
 jQuery.ajax({ 
     type: "POST",
     url: "test.php",
     data: data,
     success: function(responce){
      $("#txtHint").after(responce);
      } 
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

```html
From date: <input type="text" id="fromdate" value="2014-12-17">   To date: <input type="text" id="todate" value="2014-12-18">  
<input type="button" name="generate_report" id="generate_report" value="Generate Report" />
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>User informations will be listed here.</b></div>
```

test.php (ajax calling file)

```html
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include_once("wp-config.php");
extract($_POST);
$sql1=mysql_query("Select * from bookings where date between '".$from_date."' AND '".$to_date."'");
echo "<table border='1'>
   <tr>
  <th>id</th>
  <th>date</th>
  <th>start</th>
  <th>name</th>
  <th>email</th>
  <th>phone</th>
  <th>comments</th>
  <th>approved</th>
  </tr>";
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))
  {
    echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['date'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['start'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['comments'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['approved'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
?>
```

this demo is perfectly working and just now i have created so once check it...

[image]
[image]

Please Anyone get interest than please correct answer and give vote for this solution..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the date passed by the datepicker using AJAX is in valid format suitable for your query.

Try to display these two variables passed by HTML datepicker in your PHP page:

```
echo $_GET["fromdate"];
echo $_GET["todate"];
```

This will give you a hint of any issue if there.