# Basic php - echo mysql, how?

Tags: php, mysql, echo

I want it to echo how many posts there are in `bestallt` where its `ID` is `1` from the table `order` and display it as how many posts there are in numbers. I am connected to the database in the PHP file, that's not an issue. I'm just not sure how to put it all down in PHP, quite new to this. I just can't get it to echo what I want, nothing comes out/I get an error.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `order` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and needs to be escaped with backticks.

Comment: Or better yet, don't use order except as a key word.

Comment: Hi, you're echoing the actual query as a string not the results of the query. You need to make use of the mysqli_query function to actually go to the database and get some data. The following url is a good example of the usage of this http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your present code does not fetch the data from the database, it simply echoes the SQL query you have written.

Quite a lot more code goes in to fetching results from a mysql database, and I am not sure reproducing a full explanation here will serve anyone's interests. However, you may wish to view the examples of how to use PDO (a method of using mysql databases from php) [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php), and then either edit or re-ask your question if you find you have specific difficulties following those examples.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM order WHERE bestallt='1'"
$res=mysql_query($sql);
$arr=mysql_fetch_array($res);
echo "<pre>";print_r($arr);   //you will get whole array for matching record of your order table if found anything
```

To learn more, you can check my earlier Answer: [how generate report between the two dates using datepicker,ajax,php,mysql.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27544555/how-generate-report-between-the-two-dates-using-datepicker-ajax-php-mysql)

In that answer I have described whole working demo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<td>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM order WHERE bestallt='1'"; // Your SQL query

$response = mysql_query($sql);

if (mysql_num_rows($response) == 0) {

    // Your query returned 0 rows!

}

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($response)){

    // For each row returned from your query

    // $row is an array

    // For example, You can use it:
    echo $row['data1'];
    echo $row['data2'];
    echo $row['data3'];

    // data1, data2, data3 are the name of the fiels in your database


}


?>

</td>
```

Have a nice day!